# DateTime ToString broken?

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-core, tostring

For

```
DateTime aDate = new DateTime(2000,1,1);  
Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("d"));
```

I expect `1`, but it writes `1/1/2000`.

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) says:

`d` The day of the month, from 1 through 31.

`2009-06-01T13:45:30` -> `1`

`2009-06-15T13:45:30` -> `15`

Is there any workaround? And the same for `M`.

[dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XZfLjp)

Comment: can you try `aDate.ToString("dd")`?

Comment: "dd" works, "01"

Comment: [DateTime.Day](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.day?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Is that what you want? for month you can use MM.

Comment: Thx, bu I do not want to handle "d" as an exception, I use "dd", "ddd" and "dddd" too, but I will if there is no solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#day-d-format-specifier):

> If the "d" format specifier is used without other custom format specifiers, it's interpreted as the "d" standard date and time format specifier.

"d" is [The Short Date ("d") Format Specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-short-date-d-format-specifier)

If you need just the day of the month there is [`DateTime.Day`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.day?view=netcore-3.1):

```
Console.WriteLine(aDate.Day);
```

Alternatively, you can prefix your format string with %:

```
Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("%d"));
```

Comment: The whole "dateTime format strings" thing is, IMHO, quite messy. The Standard datetime format specifiers shouldn't even exist as strings, if you ask me. They should be an enum, which would make a clear distinction between `ToString(string format)` and `ToString(StandardFormats)`, and also, you wouldn't have to read the docs each time again and again, you could just look at the enum name.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Agreed.

Comment: However, that would make it impossible to use in string.format as shown in `Aaaaaaaa` self answer.... perhaps it is Ok as a string after all

Comment: Thanks, @JohnathanBarclay!

Comment: @ZoharPeled Having a single way to specify a standard or custom format has its benefits too, especially when globalization is required. It's handy to have a mechanism that understands both, and as written in the answer, % can be used to remove ambiguity if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You already created your DateTime object so you can access its properties from aDate.Day or aDate.Month and if you want to get day property from a datetime object simply

```
Console.WriteLine(aDate.Days.ToString()); // in your case
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right course. To print only the day, you must instead write:

```
Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("dd"));
```

And for the Month it should be:

```
Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString("MM"));
```

Comment: But what if the OP wants to use a single digit?

Comment: then it's simple, he must convert that string into an int.

Comment: But then he has to tread 'd' as a special case which he's trying to avoid

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you're trying to say. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Imagine the format is not hardcoded but part of the input (it could come from a config file, user input...). What the OP's trying to achieve is to convert a date/time according to that format, but without considering custom format specifiers (your code would not work with 'dd/MM/yyyy' for instance)

Comment: lol! This is just a preference issue. I don't buy that, again, you wouldn't want the user to input the format string directly and you just pass it `.ToString(inputFormat)`.. It's a good practice to use the input and use a `switch(){}` statement or `if` to match the desired format.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:

```
Console.WriteLine(aDate.ToString(" d"));
```

Here is important the space between the : and d. And the same for M.

Comment: But that's going to add an extra space you may not want, you could trim it but the % is cleaner